# How to cast view elements in kotlin?

Tags: android, view, kotlin

Explanation :
           I am trying to cast my `view` elements in `kotlin`. In `kotlin` there is only possible in `onCreate()` but the problem is the scope of this variable or view elements inside the `onCreate()` method only. I tried to declare outside the `onCreate()` and inside the `class`. It raised me an error.

Please help me to resolve.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{ 
    var x:Int = 10; 
    var lblValue:TextView=findViewById(R.id.lbl_value); 

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) { 
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) 
       lblValue.setText(""+getSum(10,20)); 
    } 

    fun getSum(a:Int,b:Int): Int{ 
      return a+b; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: could you post your onCreate code?

Comment: class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

    var x:Int = 10;
    var lblValue:TextView=findViewById(R.id.lbl_value);

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        lblValue.setText(""+getSum(10,20));
    }
    fun getSum(a:Int,b:Int): Int{
        return a+b;
    }
}

Comment: Multiple mistakes. You are finding view outside onCreate. You can never get view object until it's set. Find the view always after onCreate. You don't need to put semicolons, its Kotlin :) In Kotlin also there is no need to find the view by id. Read this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html